# parsing json and showing it in img src issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

When I get a json data from a php page with the help of ajax..I can show the data anywhere I want.. An example :

```
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        data: up,
        cache: false,
        success: function(r){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
        $('#test').val(obj.sentvalue);
    },
        });

<div id="test">Here the data will go</div>
```

Now I am getting an image in terms of a variable from the page..how can I show it to the right place??

```
$.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",
            data: up,
            cache: false,
            success: function(r){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
            $('#??').val(obj.image);
        },
            });

<img src = "product/(here i need to put the variable).jpg" />
```

Comment: Well, you would give your image `id="??"` though i'm not sure if that is valid. Might be better to use something like `id="myImage"`

Comment: I don't think so..It doesn't make any sense..In giving image id.. the variable can be anywhere within the id... It has to be in the right place..

Comment: So, use string manipulation to manipulate the existing src to include your string. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Comment: Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript

Answer (score 1):

Give an `ID` attribute to your image tag, so that we can easily select the element using jQuery later.

```
<img id="myImage" src="existingJunk.jpg" />
```

and in the script, read the specific property of your JSON structure and set the `src` attribute of your image.

```
success: function(r){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
        $("#myImage").attr("src",obj.ImageSource);
    },
```

Assuming your JSON data has a `ImageSource` property, like

```
{
  "ImageSource" :"http://somedomainname.com/newImage.jpg"
}
```

When working with JSON data, [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) is very useful to validate the JSON.